# How to push UIViewController in self.dismiss block?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3, dismiss

There is HomeViewController as main viewController and LeftMenuViewController presented modally over current context. Now in LeftMenuViewController there is option to open ProfileViewController but I don't want to show ProfileViewController over LeftMenuViewController, So used this code but it is not working for some unknown reason, **LeftViewController is dismissed but ProfileViewController is not pushed to front.**

```
@IBAction func editAction(_ sender: Any) {

        let homeVC:HomeViewController = self.presentingViewController!.childViewControllers[0] as! HomeViewController

        self.dismiss(animated: false) {
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                let infoVC:ProfileViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController") as! ProfileViewController
                homeVC.navigationController?.pushViewController(infoVC, animated: true)
            }

        }

    }
```

Any suggestion will be very helpfull

Comment: Could you describe what exactly does not work? `ProfileViewController` does not show or `LeftMenuViewController` not hide

Comment: LeftViewController is dismissed but ProfileViewController is not pushed to front.

Comment: do you try call `present` function

Comment: I don't want to present I want to push ViewController

Comment: probably `homeVC.navigationController` is nil

Comment: no it's not nil I checked everything is as expected but profile viewcontroller is not visible

Comment: try change `DispatchQueue.global()` to `DispatchQueue.main`

Comment: thank you but can you please explain why ?

Comment: @VarunNaharia The UI operations should be put in main queue.

Comment: @Lanford thanks for remembering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
DispatchQueue.global()
```

To

```
DispatchQueue.main
```

> UI operations should be put in main queue

Comment: The whole dispatch is not needed since you are already on the main queue.